# Cayley's expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Is Cayley's expansion 
$$\exp(-iH\delta t) \psi(x,t)=\frac{1-\frac{i\delta t}{2}H}{1+\frac{i\delta t}{2}H}\psi(x,t)$$
valid for any operator $H$? What conditions should $H$ fulfill?

Comment: What does dividing by an operator even mean? Also, this is not well-known as *"Cayley's expansion"*, and googling returns no unambiguous hints where you might have gotten this from. Additionally, this is currently a pure math question.

Comment: It appears in the Crank-Nicholson method and I do not now why sometimes this is called "Cayley's expansion".

Comment: Not seeing anything like this [on the Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method). Also, even if it appears there, dividing by an operator is still undefined.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: [This post might elucidate the topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12199/solving-schrödingers-equation-with-crank-nicolson-method).

Comment: It seems to me that OP is missing the LHS that says, $\psi(x,t+\delta t)=\exp(-iH\delta t)\psi(x,t)$. You can then clear up the "division by operator" issue.

Comment: The wiki is not everything. The dividing operator is just notation, in the literature everyone knows what that means. Just an example http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0044.pdf

Comment: Given that, this seems to be nothing more than $\exp(\epsilon A) = 1 + \epsilon A + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ applied to $\exp(\mathrm{i}H\frac{\delta t}{2})\psi(x,t+\delta t) = \exp(-\mathrm{i}H\frac{\delta t}{2})\psi(x,t)$, so it would be valid for any operator $A$.

Answer (score 5):

The expansion formally works for any operator. It's breaking the exponential as
$$
\exp(-x)=\frac{\exp(-x/2)}{\exp(x/2)}
$$
and then [expanding the numerator and denominator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) as $e^x\approx1+x$.

However, since the exponential term in the Cayley expansion comes from the time-evolution of a wave-function:
$$
\psi(x,t+\delta t)=e^{-iH\delta t}\psi(x,t)
$$
which itself comes from integrating the Schroedinger equation (and assuming that $H$ is independent of time):
$$
H\psi=i\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}
$$
I suspect that the expansion is only going to be found with the Hamiltonian operator, rather than any generic operator.